# What is the difference between engine: 'chrome' and engine: 'chromy' in backstop.config?

Tags: google-chrome, backstop.js, visual-testing

https://github.com/garris/BackstopJS
In example uses engine:'chrome', but in readme engine: 'chromy'
Is that any difference in speed or result of test?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference other than using slightly different wording for the `engine` setting. You're still using Chromy with both methods and thus your tests will execute in exactly the same way.

Older versions of `backstopjs` used Chromy by default. The only available alternatives to Chromy were to use `slimerjs` or `casperjs`. See this from the older version of the `backstopjs` documentation:

---

**Chrome-Headless (The latest webkit library)**

This will also enable the very cool chromy.js (https://github.com/OnetapInc/chromy) library. (When creating onBefore and onReady scripts please make sure you are referring to the Chromy script documentation. Casper features will not work with this setting.)

`"engine": "chrome"`

---

So when you set your `engine` setting to `chrome` in the older versions, it would default-use Chromy as its engine.

However `backstopjs` has since been updated and now supports `puppeteer` as well as `chromy` and, since this change, you are required to set your `engine` as follows:

---

`"engine": "puppeteer"`

or

`"engine": "chromy"`

---

I would suggest that the reason for the difference in the examples is simply because the example in question is using an older version of `backstopjs` where you only needed to set `chrome` in order to use Chromy as the default engine.

Comment: "Chromy is no longer supported in version 5+. Please use version 4.x.x for chromy support."